# Wordpress Ubermenu, как сделать иконку с беджем вроде (1)?

Tags: wordpress

Есть элемент меню "Новости" (верхнего уровня, естественно), с иконкой (глобус).
Нужно сделать, чтобы при наличии новых новостей у иконки появлялся бедж типа такого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну насчет AJAX и т.д. - все ясно, но как именно добавить бедж к иконке элемента Ubermenu? Есть ли там что-то готовое или нужен велосипед?

Answer (score 0):

Если вы имеете в виду как реалитзовать это на HTML и CSS то вот так например:

**Вариант №1**

```css
body{ 
    background-color: #5ec246;
    padding: 10px;
}
.menu {
    max-width: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #0557a3;
    border-radius: 12px;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px #0000008f;
}
.menu:before {
    content: "1";
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    position: absolute;
    right: -8px;
    top: -8px;
    color: white;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="menu"></div>  
</body>
```

**Вариант №2**

```css
body{ 
        background-color: #5ec246;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    .menu {
        max-width: 100px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: #0557a3;
        border-radius: 12px;
        position: relative;
        box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px #0000008f;
    }
    .count  {
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        background: red;
        border-radius: 50px;
        border: 2px solid white;
        position: absolute;
        right: -8px;
        top: -8px;
        color: white;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
            -ms-flex-pack: center;
                justify-content: center;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
            -ms-flex-align: center;
                align-items: center;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="menu">
   <div class="count">1</div>
 </div>  
</body>
```

Comment: Это я и сам сделаю. 
Надо именно для Ubermenu, нет ли там уже готового варианта.

Comment: в плагинах смотрел подобное ничего нет.

Comment: @koshkashoshka если вы можете сделать это самостоятельно, что вам мешает вставить этот код в Ubermenu?

Comment: @KAGGDesign Боязнь того, что изобретаю велосипед и может он предоставляет готовое решение. Незнание его внутренностей, отсюда вопросы как именно его туда вставить.